How do I get access to a single integer custom property within geometry nodes?
I've tried following some older walkthoughs that I saw but my custom property did not show up in the group input node. I've tried numerous times but I can't get at the integer.
Unlike in How can i use custom attributes in geometry nodes? I don't want to move the element, I want to change the UV coordinates on a generated texture from the custom property on the object.
I saw this one here, Can I set an instance's custom property with an attribute node? , and it seems like they were able to do what I'm trying to do, so I know it's possible, but no matter what I do the property doesn't show.

Custom properties can't be read in Geometry Nodes as far as I know... Of course there's a chance you mean something different than what Blender documentation means by this term - hard to say, as you never make a screenshot of what you mean, you point to a link of a guy that didn't make a screenshot of what he means and says he is unsure of the terminology, and you draw a conclusion from an answer that doesn't actually use a custom property, that it is possible... And most importantly, explain why you need this, so we can advise the best workflow.
